# Songs of Conquest can't play cutscenes after winning a mission on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: video, gaming, ubuntu-18.04, codec

Songs of Conquest can't play a cutscene / video after winning a mission in campaign on Ubuntu 18.04. After you win a mission, there should be a bard singing a song. The screen just stays black. How do you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The cutscenes are videos, so you need the right codec to view them. Wine installs a codec for you but, it makes a wrong assumption-

Ubuntu 18.04 uses glic 2.27 while the newer lutris wine versions installing a gstreamer which wants to use glib 2.28. This fails, so you have to make sure, wine is using your system gstreamer codec, which works with glibc 2.27.

You can use these command to fix it, after you found out which path wine installed the wrong codecs (right click on game and view logs, after you played a cutscene video in game):

```
find /usr/ -name "libgstlibav.so"
#/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so
mv /home/USERNAME/.local/share/lutris/runners/wine/lutris-GE-Proton7-27-x86_64/lib64/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so /home/USERNAME/.local/share/lutris/runners/wine/lutris-GE-Proton7-27-x86_64/lib64/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so.remove_me
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so /home/USERNAME/.local/share/lutris/runners/wine/lutris-GE-Proton7-27-x86_64/lib64/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so
find /usr/ -name "libgstshm.so"
#/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstshm.so
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstshm.so /home/USERNAME/.local/share/lutris/runners/wine/lutris-GE-Proton7-27-x86_64/lib64/gstreamer-1.0/libgstshm.so
```

If you can't find the libav and gestreamer files install the libav and gstreamer packages from synaptic / apt-get.